# NOT IN missing results

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a pretty simple query, "I want all the user_ids which don't have a role_type of 'GROUP'. The following sqlfiddle gives the correct result I want http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a9640/1 but when I run the query on my actual MySQL DB it doesn't return the 2 results with user_id=13565 and I've no idea why.

The subquery gives the single answer 8301 and indeed if I manually enter this value into the 
brackets i.e.

```
select * from role 
where role.user_id not in (
  select role.user_id 
  from role
  where role.role_type = 'GROUP' 
)
and (group_id=1465 or group_id=6314)
order by user_id
```

Then the 2 missing results somehow reappear.  Any ideas why these results are stripped out when I use the subquery with NOT IN?

Comment: is `group_id` null for those rows?

Comment: Don't show us the data with which it works, but the one where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben,  group_id is not NULL for those rows, the data is exactly the same as in the SQLfiddle (well it's missing a role_id column but that's not NULL either)

Comment: @fancyPants, the data for the rows I want is the same as the SQL fiddle...I'll add the missing 'role_id' colulmn

Comment: I have no local MySQL instance handy to test, but if the data and schema and query are identical in your instance as in the fiddle, this should work. What happens if you paste the entire script of the fiddle (including the create and insert) into MySQL?

Comment: I'm running a "read only" ID so can't create tables, thanks for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A known confusion with `not in` is that the all rows get filtered out if the subquery returns `NULL` for any of the elements.  This can be fixed by checking for this explicitly:

```
select r.*
from role r
where r.user_id not in (select r2.user_id 
                        from role r2
                        where r2.role_type = 'GROUP' and r2.user_id is not null
                       ) and
      r.group_id in (1465, 6314)
order by r.user_id;
```

I prefer using `not exists`, because it doesn't have this issue with `NULL`s:

```
select r.*
from role r
where not exists (select r2.user_id 
                  from role r2
                  where r2.role_type = 'GROUP' and r2.user_id = r.user_id
                ) and
      r.group_id in (1465, 6314)
order by r.user_id;
```

EDIT:

I suspect the problem is that user 13565 has a `role_type = 'GROUP'` but for a different `group_id`.  Perhaps this is the query you really want:

```
select r.*
from role r
where not exists (select 1
                  from role r2
                  where r2.role_type = 'GROUP' and r2.user_id = r.user_id and
                        r2.group_id in (1465, 6314)
                ) and
      r.group_id in (1465, 6314)
order by r.user_id;
```

Comment: "*a known problem*" is somewhat an exaggeration. This is by design in the SQL language.

Comment: It STILL misses out those last 2 results. It's just not behaving properly.  If I run that query on SQL fiddle then I get 5 results as expected, if I run on my DB then I only get 3!  If I manually put 8301 in the sebquery then I get 5.

Comment: @DrDan . . . My guess is that you have some unexpected data in your database.  Perhaps `GROUP` is misnamed or something else is different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I really don't know anyone who finds the behavior of `not in` with `NULL` to be intuitive.  Of course, it follows from the semantics of `NULL` values, so the behavior is proper.  I changed the word "problem" to "confusion".

Comment: *confusion* nails it ;)

Comment: If I run `select * from role where role_type='GROUP' and user_id='8301'` then it brings back the record just fine...very odd.

Comment: Just to prove I'm not going insane here is the table structure [link](https://dumpyourphoto.com/photo/EVn9AszKcf), the full query [link](https://dumpyourphoto.com/photo/LEgWCNO3kf), your query [link](https://dumpyourphoto.com/photo/LrDBEYDKXJ) and your query with hardcoded 8301 [link](https://dumpyourphoto.com/photo/73SpvB0vPt)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh man you're right! `user_id=13565 group_type='GROUP' group_id=3128`  Thanks for pointing out the obvious mistake, I need to rethink my query.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess what I really need is "Give me the GroupIDs for which there is a user **in that group** without the 'GROUP' setting".  My query is missing out users who have the 'GROUP' setting for **any** group

Comment: @DrDan . . . If that is another question, you can ask that as a question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery is not the best way when we think about performance.

Here is the query you're looking for, **without use of subquery**:

```
SELECT R.*
FROM role R
LEFT OUTER JOIN role R2 ON R2.user_id = R.user_id
                         AND R2.role_type = 'GROUP'
WHERE R.group_id IN (1465, 6314)
    AND R2.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY R.user_id
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: That gives 2 results in the SQL fiddle rather than the 5 I need.  In my DB it gives 0 as again the results with group_id=6314 just aren't coming back for some reason unless I manually enter 8301 in the subquery

Comment: I fixed my query few seconds ago, there was a typo in the `IN` clause (1456 instead of 1465).

Comment: Didn't see that typo, thanks for changing.  I'm still not getting those 2 results back though.  I just can't see why, this should be so simple! :)

Comment: @DrDan I just copy/paste the query to execute it in your `SQL Fiddle` and the expected results are returned. My query is exactly the same as yours, i just optimised it (better performance as using a subquery and more readable in my opinion).